# How to get permission of video downloader from appstore?

Tags: ios, flutter, download, app-store, download-manager

I made an app which enable us to download tiktok video by using api to extract tiktok video url and ffmpeg library. However, app store rejected it because of Guideline 5.2.3 - Legal - Intellectual Property.

"Your app allows users to save or download music, video, or other media content without authorization from the relevant third-party sources."

In app store, a lot of video downloaders are listed such as tik saver, tiksave, video saver and so on.
How do they release their video downloader?
Can I get permission from appstore, if I do not specify the third party video's name, such as "TikTok"?

Comment: Maybe they have relevant authorization from TikTok and the content creators?

Comment: Did you find any way to fix it? @ki1

Comment: Nothing．．． @yildirimatcioglu

Comment: I have the same problem, there are tons of doing this but they are not allowing me. I think there is a way to get permission from these social medias. We should find that permission

Comment: you got any solution @yildirimatcioglu